# Nbackup taking backup from a remote alias

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

Is it possible to take a backup from a remote machine to local machine using nbackup? My database is in a server and I need to take the backup to my local PC using NBackup.

When I tried, it is not allowing to give the backup path to a local machine.

Comment: You can use the service manager to perform a nbackup on remote Firebird database, however IIRC the backup file will be local to the same machine as the database. If you want to have a remote backup, you'd need to use gbak.

Comment: thanks i tried it and its working now. i am moving the file to the local machine after taking the backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nbackup itself can only back up local databases. However, in Firebird 2.5 and above its backup and restore tasks can also be performed remotely through the Services Manager.](https://www.firebirdsql.org/pdfmanual/html/nbackup-overview.html)

You can use `gbak` to backup a remote database to local machine.

[How to backup the remote database to a local hard disk?](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq62/)

> Here's the GBAK command:
>
> gbak -b -v 192.168.0.20:/dbases/mydb.fdb C:\mybackup.fbk -user SYSDBA
>   -pass 123456